# Error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') + Migrations + secrets.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

When running the command: "dotnet ef migrations add init -o" it gives an error for not finding the database connection string. I'm using the file "secrets.json" and the connection string is correctly configured in it, but it's not finding it.

[connectionString.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD2EY.png)

[Migrationsfailure.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvDeU.png)

Comment: Please share you Startup file as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your problem is that you are simply not finding the file "secrets.json". I already had the same problem.
To confirm, right-click on the tab where the file is open in VS and choose: "Open Containing Folder"

[image]

Now open your project in file edit mode and look for the "UserSecretsId" tag. Confirm that the value of this key has exactly the same name as the folder where the "secrets.json" file is

You will also find more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows

Comment: [@alinefz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20212507/alinefz) Just take a look at [What is voting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)